# Touch input does not work right when phone is plugged in

Tags: usb, touchscreen

Basically touch input either doesn't work at all, or works erratically.  This includes the the lock screen too.  It happens both plugged in to a USB port or to the outlet.

I've had this problem on two phones, and HTC Nexus One and and Samsung Nexus S.

Does anyone have any idea about what the cause of this and if I can do anything to fix it?  Have you seen this problem?

Comment: Never heard of it. My Droid works just fine when plugged in to a USB port as well as an AC outlet.

Comment: The only reason I can think of for this happening on two phones is that you have a buggy app installed on both, although I don't know how an app could do that.

Comment: I've seen this on the Droid X.  Touch input can sometimes be sluggish or non-responsive.

Comment: related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9416/no-touchscreen-response-when-charging

Comment: are you using original charger?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with the HTC Nexus One and it was directly related to heat. Whenever the phone got too hot the touch screen would flake out. Charging the phone makes it heat up, the worst time for me was when it was in the car dock, heat from charging and from the screen being on all the time. When ever it did this all I had to do was hold it in front of the AC vent for 15 - 30 seconds and the screen would work normally.

Comment: Holding your phone infront of AC is bad for the phone screen and IC. Let it cool normally or one can remove the charger from phone, use it and again put it back to charging. But yes, heating is the issue. This normally happens also when you phone is overcharged.

Comment: @Lucky I did this to confirm that it was the heat causing the problem more than anything else. But I am interested to hear your theory on how cooling it off with the AC vent would cause damage to the screen or the IC.

Comment: All I'm saying is when your phone is hot(around 50°C) the moisture from AC vent condenses and might form water droplets inside your screen when exposed directly. Read this too http://www.userbytes.com/how-cold-weather-can-affect-electronics

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered this problem with my Samsung Galaxy II S, but only when I am using a third party charger of dubious quality.  The hardware buttons continue to work but the touchscreen becomes unresponsive.  The issue does not occur with the OEM charger.

Comment: My friend also had similar problem with Motorola Milestone third party chargers.

Comment: I had this issue with my Droid Incredible. Only did it with a generic charger never with the OEM charger.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue happening with three different devices - Motorola Backflip, Motorola Defy and Genesis GT-1230. The cause is always cheap third-party chargers -- and in my case, it works fine when plugged to the computer via USB cable (it's an original Motorola cable).